# What changes have been made to my cpanel?

Tags: linux, log-files

What is the most easily accessible way to track changes made to cPanel?

Ideally I would like to create a script which gathers information from the cPanel logs, but are there any scripts already created to do this?

Comment: *to* cpanel, or *by* cpanel?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure this is what you want, but it might help you:

If you have logwatch installed, go to `/etc/log.d/conf/logwatch.conf`

Inside change mailto to your own e-mail address. There will also be an option to change the level of detail to either Low, Medium or High.

You should be able to run a test with: `./usr/share/logwatch/scripts/logwatch.pl --range today`.